# Rest Web API returning null response

Tags: php, json

I'm new to Web Services, so I hope I explain this correctly.

I'm writing a RESTful Web API but my app is getting a null response back. My code snippets:

```
function sendResponse($status = 200, $body = '', $content_type = 'application/json')
{
    $status_header = 'HTTP/1.1 ' . $status . ' ' . getStatusCodeMessage($status);
    header($status_header);
    header('Content-type: ' . $content_type);
    echo $body;
}

function find_events()
{
  global $user_name, $password, $database, $serverip;

  $db_handle = mysql_connect($serverip, $user_name, $password);
  $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);
  if ($db_found) {;
        $result = array();
        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM Event_Record";
        $sqlresult = mysql_query($SQL);
        while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlresult) ) {
            $arr = array_map('utf8_encode', $db_field);
            $result[] = $arr;
        }
    } else {
        $result = "error";
    }
    mysql_close($db_handle);

  sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));
}
```

Based on other answers I've seen, I added the 'utf8_encode' in case that was the problem...

When I test it with a browser I get the following, which tells me that the result to the json_encode is not null:

```
[{"eventGUID":"1","latitude":"-71.466","longitude":"42.7624","type":"1","title":"United Way Event","address":"100 Main Street, Nashua MH","start":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","end":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","description":"We appreciae your hard work","create":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","expire":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","owner":"1"},{"eventGUID":"2","latitude":"-71.4648","longitude":"42.7624","type":"2","title":"New Event","address":"Nashua, NH","start":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","end":"2001-00-00 00:00:00","description":"Event","create":"2002-00-00 00:00:00","expire":"2002-00-00 00:00:00","owner":"1"}]
```

I added a test routine:

```
function do_test()
{
    $test_result = array();
    $test_result[] = "TEST:'1',RESPONSE:'AOK'";
    $test_result[] = "TEST:'2',RESPONSE:'GOOD'";

  sendResponse(200, json_encode($test_result));
}
```

My app does get the correct response from the test.  Which seems to indicate that the protocols and headers are fine.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your function `sendResponse` doesn't actually send anything anywhere.

Comment: When I call do_test() I get a response back to my app with the data that the web service is supplying.  But when I call find_events() I get a null response.  Both call the same sendResponse() function

Comment: `if ($db_found) {;` what do you think this semicolon is doing?

Answer (score 0):

in the part: sendResponse(200, json_encode($value));

I do not see where you are setting the value for $value. I think you meant it to be $result

sendResponse(200, json_encode($result));

Comment: Sorry, that was a cut and paste problem.  I edited the above to the current version.

Comment: did you try dumping the contents of result before passing it to the sendresponse function to vwrfy you are actually getting data back from your query?

Comment: Yes, I did.  And the browser results above would the the output of the sendResponse() function, so I know the results are getting all the way to sendResponse.  I also made sure all literals started with lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

I would first initiate the $result outside of the if statement with an error statement. If your db call fails you need to send a 401 or some other HTTP error code. Also you may need to force the buffer to output your echo.
And to answer a question you didn't ask, you should use a framework (even a micro framework) to send API responses because it will save you tons of time later and make your users happier.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I answered by own question.

When I commented on the last answer, I decided to try something.  I changed eventGUID to event_guid in the database and it magically worked.  Although it works, I am still confused because I know that upper-case letters are allowed in JSON, AND whatever was blocking the results was between the web service sending the response and my app getting the response.

Thank you for the help!!